# Toggle Switch React Native Firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, switch-statement

I'm building react native app using firestore, so i this toggle that switch user location on and off but it doesn't seems working to post to firebase

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            toggled: this.props.currentUser.locationOn,
        }
      }
      
      toggleSwitch (value){
        this.setState({toggled: value})
        firebase.firestore().collection("users")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
          geo_point: new firestore.GeoPoint(-6.6004, 106.8092),
          locationOn: value
        })
        console.log('tes switch', value)
      }
      
      render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Switch onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
                    value={this.state.toggled}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way with an arrow function like

```
toggleSwitch = (value) => {
   this.setState({toggled: value})
   ...
}
```

Comment: What’s the different though?

Comment: @Ronald `onValueChange` need's callback so that's why use like a callback instead of normal function